# How can I iteratively modify sub-blocks of an array without using a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sparse numpy array whose values are either 0 or 1. I also have a kernel who dimensions are k x k. For every non-zero value I would like to take the k x k sub-block of the array centered at that value and add my kernel to it. I would like to do this efficiently, hopefully without using any for loops.

So far I have tried this:

```
import numpy as np

def sparse_convolutionv2(input, kernel):
    kernel = np.flipud(np.fliplr(kernel))
    
    # Getting nonzero indices
    non_zero_indices = np.transpose(np.nonzero(input))
    
    # Obtain windows
    row_start, row_end = non_zero_indices[:, 0] - kernel.shape[0] // 2, non_zero_indices[:, 0] + kernel.shape[0] // 2 + 1
    col_start, col_end = non_zero_indices[:, 1] - kernel.shape[1] // 2, non_zero_indices[:, 1] + kernel.shape[1] // 2 + 1
    output = np.zeros_like(input)

    # Add kernel
    for i in range(len(row_start)):
        output[row_start[i]:row_end[i], col_start[i]:col_end[i]] = np.add(output[row_start[i]:row_end[i], col_start[i]:col_end[i]], kernel)
    return output
```

Comment: you mean you want a vectorised method presumably ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like a vectorized method

Comment: First, when you say 'sparse', you mean mostly 0s, not a `scipy.sparse` matrix?  What if two nonzero values are close together, and their 'kernels' overlap?

Comment: Yes, by sparse I mean mostly zeros. If 2 'kernels' overlap at an array element then that element in the output array should have value 2.

Comment: `np.add.at` might work for you.  Read its docs.  Otherwise `np.add` with duplicate indices will only use one.  In gereral though, 'iteratively <==> loops'

Comment: When we talking 'vectorize' in `numpy`, we mean use the compiled methods - loops are still done, but in faster code.   But those methods nearly always work "in-parallel", in the sense that each element is used independently.  Sequential methods are few - ufuncs have a `reduce/accumulate`, and the afore mentioned `at`.  In general though sequential operations are too variable and complicated to implement with this building block approach.